# Angular 2 Object Interpolation Issue in NgFor/NgIf

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an `*ngFor` for an array of User objects. Inside this `ngFor` is a div with an `*ngIf`, and inside this div, is an `<img>` tag with an interpolated `src` attribute.

```
<md-card *ngFor="let user of users" [user]="user" style="background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48) !important;">
  <md-card-title-group class="gotham" style="color: rgb(93, 93, 93) !important; font-family: 'Gotham' !important;">

  <md-card-title style="width: 200px !important; text-overflow: ellipsis !important; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;"><span class="gotham">{{user.username}}</span></md-card-title>
  <md-card-subtitle class="gotham" style="color: rgb(161, 161, 161) !important;"><span class="gotham">User since {{ user.datejoined | date:'fullDate' }}</span></md-card-subtitle>
  <md-list>
  </md-list>
  <div *ngIf="user.fbdetails" style="display: inline-block; float: right;"><img style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="app/assets/facebook_circle_color-512.png"/></div>
  <div *ngIf="user.twitterdetails" style="display: inline-block; float: right;"><img style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" src="app/assets/twitter_circle_color-256.png"/></div>
  <i *ngIf="!user.fbdetails.picture.data.url" class="material-icons" style="font-size: 60px; color: white !important; display: inline-block; float: right;">people</i>
  <div *ngIf="user.fbdetails" style="display: inline-block; float: right;"><img style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" src="{{user.fbdetails.picture.data.url}}"/></div>
  </md-card-title-group>
</md-card>
```

Now the div that wraps the `<img>` should not display if there is no `user.fbdetails` in the object hierarchy. This applies to almost all of the users in question (most do not have fbdetails). Which means the interpolated value of the binding `{{user.fbdetails.picture.data.url}}` is not populated, but the `*ngIf` should prevent those bindings from being present if there are no `fbdetails`. However, I still get a `Cannot read property "picture" of undefined` error, even though that should never come into play because of the `*ngIf`.

This is something that I did fairly often in Angular 1, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the safe-navigation operator should fix your problem

```
<i *ngIf="!user.fbdetails?.picture?.data?.url"
```

This way Angular doesn't throw if `fbdetails` is `null`.

Comment: Didn't even know this existed. Is this an angular 2 thing or a typescript thing? Where did this come from?

Comment: it's Angular2 template syntax. AFAIK it is considered to be added to ES6 but didn't land yet.

Answer (score 0):

Error that you are getting is from

```
  <i *ngIf="!user.fbdetails.picture.data.url" class="material-icons" style="font-size: 60px; color: white !important; display: inline-block; float: right;">people</i>
```

It is trying to read picture from user.fbdetails